# Given $K$ compact, where $K \subseteq U$ open, $\exists \epsilon > 0$ such that $\bigcup_{x \in K} B(x,\epsilon) \subseteq U$

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

Given a metric space $X$ and $K \subseteq X$ compact, where $K \subseteq U$ such that $U$ is open. I am trying to show that there exists some $\epsilon > 0: \bigcup_{x \in K} B(x,\epsilon) \subseteq U$.

Since $K$ is compact any open cover $\{U_i\}_{i \in I}$ of $K$ admits a finite subcover. $U$ is an open cover of $K$ and given $\epsilon > 0, \bigcup_{x \in K} B(x,\epsilon)$ is an open cover as well.  Furthermore, since $U$ is open, there is some $r > 0$ such that $B(x,r) \subseteq U$. I'd like to conclude that $\bigcup_{x \in K} B(x,r) \subseteq U$ but I don't think this is true. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use the definition of open at each point to get a little neighborhood of radius $r_x$ around each $x \in K$.  This covers $K$ but by compactness you only need finitely many such neighborhoods.  Can you finish?

Comment: I suggest starting with consideration of a single point $x\in K$.

Comment: @Randall You mean I should consider for each $x \in K$ a ball $B(x,r_x)$ and reduce the set of  these balls to finitely many?

Comment: Yes.  That should get you close.  The problem is that you need a universal $\epsilon$ for all, and that is easiest done when you have only finitely many.

Comment: If I have finite finite balls then I could take the maximum $r_x$ I guess

Comment: Or the minimum....

Comment: @Randall Let's see if I got your suggestion. For every $x \in K \Rightarrow x \in U \Rightarrow \exists r_x > 0: B(x,r_x) \subseteq U \Rightarrow \bigcup_{x \in K} B(x,r_x) \subseteq U$. Since $K$ is compact we can take a finite subcover $\{B(x_1, r_{x_1}), ..., B(x_k, r_{x_k})\}$ and then  if we consider $\epsilon = min_{i = 1...k} \{r_{x_i}\}$, we get that  $\bigcup_{x \in K} B(x,\epsilon) \subseteq U$.

Comment: I think that looks quite close to it.

Answer (score 2):

Using compactness, produce $x_1, \ldots,x_n, \epsilon_1, \ldots, \epsilon_n$ such that $K \subseteq B(x_1, \epsilon_1) \cup \ldots \cup B(x_n, \epsilon_n) \subseteq U$. If $n = 0$, then $K = \emptyset$, and the problem is trivial. We now consider the case $n > 0$.

Define the function $g(x) = \sup\limits_{1 \leq j \leq n} (\epsilon_j - d(x, x_j))$. Note that $g : K \to (0, \infty)$ is continuous. Thus, its image is compact. Then take some $\epsilon > 0$ such that $g(K) \subseteq (\epsilon, \infty)$. I claim $\bigcup\limits_{x \in K} B(x, \epsilon) \subseteq U$.

For consider some $x \in K$. Then $\epsilon < g(x)$. Thus, we can take some $j$ such that $\epsilon < \epsilon_j - d(x, x_j)$. Then we have $B(x, \epsilon) \subseteq B(x_j, \epsilon_j) \subseteq U$ by the triangle inequality.

Comment: This looks good. It would be great if you adapted it to follow the proof the user who asked the question sketched above, as it is perhaps more intuitive.